# Python: Retrieving WordNet hypernyms from offset input

Tags: python, nltk, wordnet

I know how to get hypernyms of words, like so :

```
word = 'girlfriend'
word_synsets = wn.synsets(word)[0]

hypernyms = word_synsets.hypernym_paths()[0]

for element in hypernyms:
    print element


Synset('entity.n.01')
Synset('physical_entity.n.01')
Synset('causal_agent.n.01')
Synset('person.n.01')
Synset('friend.n.01')
Synset('girlfriend.n.01')
```

My question is, if I wanted to search for the `hypernym` of an `offset`, how would I change this current code?

For example, given the offset `01234567-n` its hypernyms are outputted.  The hypernyms can either be outputted in `synset` form like my example, or (and preferably) as `offset` form.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a cute function from [`pywsd`](https://twitter.com/jeremys/status/701092317046812672) that's originally from http://moin.delph-in.net/SemCor

```
def offset_to_synset(offset):
    """ 
    Look up a synset given offset-pos 
    (Thanks for @FBond, see http://moin.delph-in.net/SemCor)
    >>> synset = offset_to_synset('02614387-v')
    >>> print '%08d-%s' % (synset.offset, synset.pos)
    >>> print synset, synset.definition
    02614387-v
    Synset('live.v.02') lead a certain kind of life; live in a certain style
    """
    return wn._synset_from_pos_and_offset(str(offset[-1:]), int(offset[:8]))
```

Comment: `wn.synset('live.v.02').hypernyms()`

Comment: `offset_to_synset('01234567-n').hypernyms()`